# summary function in R: How to build a table

Tags: r, xtable

I need to approximate and build the data in the table(code below).

```
results <- read.table(file='results',header =TRUE)
out = nls(y ~(a*exp(b*x) - 1), data=results, start=list(a=0.081, b=20.89))
out <- summary(out)
```

I found the approximation using the function **summary()**, but I do not know how to build a table with approximation results?
Please help me!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You code has some problems - see the last two lines. Also, it is not clear to me what you try to achieve. It is better to take time to ask your question.

```
out = nls(y ~(a*exp(b*x) - 1), data=results, start=list(a=0.081, b=20.89))
out_summary <- summary(out)

# table from
out_summary$parameters

# latex from
xtable(out_summary$parameters)
```